# Java netty socket.io - Max Http Content Length

Tags: java, socket.io, netty-socketio

I'm new to socket.io, and I had a problem: I would like my server to send a large amount of data to my client, and so I tried to modify the value of maxHttpContentLength, except that this variable is an integer so I can't go above 2^31-1, or 2048 MB. How can I increase this limit?

I tried to change the value to 0 or -1 for example, but it's even worse, we can't even send a single byte anymore.

Thanks !